# Comparison between orginal and modified DLL files with x64dbg

Tags: dll, x64dbg, bin-diffing

Is it possible to find the modifications between a original DLL file and a modified one using x64dbg?

And, if I can't do it with x64dbg, what tool would be better than a debugger to find the modifications done on assembly code between the two files?

Comment: Do you want to compare two DLL files or do you want to see run-time patches on a DLL file?

Comment: i have original DLL file and the patched version of it and i want to know which line been patched

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't use a debugger to search for differences. You should use a diff tool. Of course, most diff tools work on ASCII text, but there are some that deal with binary files.

Some examples:

- [radiff2](https://radareorg.github.io/blog/posts/binary-diffing/)
- [HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/)

There are more and you probably will find one that matches exactly your need.
If you would like to see your modifications in a nice visual manner with already bytes being presented as opcodes there are some options too. I haven't used them (so can't give you my recommendations) but there are at least two that I know of:

- [BinNavi](https://www.zynamics.com/binnavi.html)
- [PatchDiff 2](https://github.com/filcab/patchdiff2)

Comment: how am i suppose to install patchdiff 2 with IDA and use it,there is no installation or using guide

Comment: Compile and then put in plugins folder as you would do with any other plugin

Comment: i tried that already but got too many errors and undefined variables, is there a compiled one?

Comment: I’ll try to see if I can get that compiling

Comment: would be really great help

Comment: I don't have IDA SDK but it looks like if you have access then it should compile

Answer (score 2):

In Windows, perhaps the simplest possibility is the built-in File Compare command with its /B (binary) switch, to be used from the command-line. It lists all different bytes together with their file offset.

Usage:

fc /B filepath1 filepath2

Comment: i want to see the opcode different not the binarry

Comment: The file compare gives you the file offsets of the differences in your binaries. From these you can easily get the opcode diffs in a debugger. Should be no problem at all.

Comment: always give me this error, FC: cannot open C:\PROGRAM - No such file or folder

Comment: quote your path like fc /b "c:\prxxx\yyy ddd" "d:\xx xx xx\yyy   yyy"  spaces are treated as delimiters for most of the console apps  so it cant find your file that has a space in the path

Comment: hundred lines of binaries and last line is FC: "c:\prxxx\yyy ddd" longer than "d:\xx xx xx\yyy yyy"